# Dealing with arbitrary objects in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

New to TypeScript. I have something like this:

```js
class Foo {
   dowork(data: object): void {
      if ('some_prop' in data && Array.isArray(data.some_props)) {
         // ...
      }
   }

   main(): void {
      const json = '{ ... }';
      const data = JSON.parse(json);
      if (data instanceof Object) {
         this.dowork(data);
   }
}

( new Foo() ).main();
```

It fails with

```
src/index.ts:388:53 - error TS2339: Property 'some_prop' does not exist on type 'object'.

388       if ('some_prop' in data && Array.isArray(data.some_prop)) {
                                                        ~~~~~~~~~
```

I believe I can get around the issue using

```js
interface ObjectWithSomeProp {
   some_prop: any,
}

function is_object_with_some_prop(x: any): x is ObjectWithSomeProp {
   return typeof x === 'object' && 'some_prop' in x;
}
```

I will be doing multiple such tests. Do I need to create an interface and test for each one, or is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Easiest way

Make a generic `hasProp` typeguard

```
const hasProp = <T extends string>(obj: object, prop: T): obj is { [K in T]: any } => {
  return prop in obj;
}

const someFunc = (obj: object) => {
  // obj is of type object and we have no clue if he has 'foo' prop or not
  if (hasProp(obj, 'foo')) {
    // obj is of type { foo: any }, so we can use foo now
    const some = obj.foo;
  }
}
```

you will have what you need, **but it will break type of obj**, it is not a solution if you want to use some props of `obj` other than `foo` in the `if` block.

#### A little bit better

Add second generic to describe object type and keep it as is

```
const hasProp = <O extends object, T extends string>(obj: O, prop: T): obj is O & { [K in T]: any } => {
  return prop in obj;
}

const someFunc = (obj: { bar: number }) => {
  // obj is of type { bar: number } and 'foo' prop is not here
  if (hasProp(obj, 'foo')) {
    // obj is of type { bar: number } & { foo: any }
    // so we managed to persist previous obj type and add 'foo' after typeguard use
    const fooProp = obj.foo;
    const barProp = obj.bar;
  }
}
```

We did not break obj type and managed to add foo prop, but still, foo type is `any`. And probably we want to persist type of foo prop too, so we need to infer its type from obj.

#### Best solution

We first define a type for `ObjectWithProp`, what keeps a type of the object, if it already has `foo` prop, and adds it as `any` if not

```
type ObjectWithProp<O extends object, P extends string> = P extends keyof O
  ? O
  : O & { [K in P]: any };
```

Then we just use it in the typeguard and have desired result

```
const hasProp = <O extends object, P extends string>(obj: O, prop: P): obj is ObjectWithProp<O, P> => {
  return prop in obj;
}

const someFunc = (obj: { bar: number, foo: string }) => {
  if (hasProp(obj, 'foo')) {
    // obj kept it's type and we can still see that foo is a string
    const some = obj.foo;
  }
}

const someFunc2 = (obj: { bar: number }) => {
  if (hasProp(obj, 'foo')) {
    // if obj has no 'foo' prop initially, then it will be added as `any`
    const some = obj.foo;
  }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwgY2AdQJbABYAUBOA9mADwxQQAewEAdgCYDOUhiKwANFLhdXU1EbB8GWgHMAfFAC83XjQbMA1hBCEAZrABQUKAH5tugFywoAMigBvKAG0A0lFHcAuiYCGtEFAC+Abi1ayIS0QlDYbowExDJQZPL8zKxIqFw8VAoCQiLiEgAUSSYwXGBEYCa4AJQmSY7M8MnoWHilZKlS0lKWOlD4EMAArvi0UCXRTkn+3gFBIcCChAC2EABi-bTIMfmIJtZwbvgmtP0LcBD4XOqEhCZZomI+FTKd3RiaueGRpVsIXADkl4RfhVHl1dLoAPTgliIKAqMBzLC-ZigSBQDz0KAAd2gyA8gmAGAANoTBBBoDg3HMAbV8dkxN1dDNQoxFtBZEkAHQA-y6KZTQLBZms1brABMmwKVigewOUCOJzODyeVhebw+UTA3z+AKBIIZUEhjk0NQ+csIUH+V1+I1KjloWAwbmJIC4ODojjmmKJJNOaPo9AgGIiUAABh4QCH9Uy5iyljFOdzunygA)

Comment: Re "*Make a generic `hasProp` typeguard*", First thing I tried after composing the question, but I failed. Thanks, I'll look at the other solutions you provided shortly. I'm sure I'll learn a lot :)

Comment: It was a good idea actually :). Also typescript default naming convention is using camel case for functions and variables, so probably you should not use snake case in JS.

Comment: There's a good reason CamelCase was universally avoided for over 30 years: It's a lot harder to read. It's especially hard to read for some non-native English speakers, since they would have a hard time distinguising where each word ends. There in lies the reason we put space between words. Spacing is good.

Comment: Also, it's very useful to use different conventions for type identifiers and other identifiers. As such, I follow the long-standing convention of using CamelCase for type identifers and not for others. If I collaborate on another project, I'll follow their conventions, but I'll stick to the CS ideal of maximizing readability and maintainability on my own projects.

Comment: I personally follow typescript guidelines and name variables and functions in camelCase, types in PascalCase and constants is ALL_CAPS. But it is totally up to you as long as it's your personal project, I only mentioned default convention.

Answer (score 0):

I defined these types and helpers:

```js
type JsonValue = null | string | number | boolean | JsonArray | JsonDict;
type JsonArray = JsonValue[];
interface JsonDict extends Record<string, JsonValue> { }

function is_json_dict(x: JsonValue): x is JsonDict {
   return x instanceof Object && !Array.isArray(x);
}

// For symmetry. Could simply use Array.isArray(x).
function is_json_array(x: JsonValue): x is JsonArray {
   return Array.isArray(x);
}
```

One can use the near-identical code:

```js
class Foo {
   dowork(data: JsonDict): void {
      if (is_json_array(data.some_props)) {
         // ...
      }
   }

   main(): void {
      const json = '{ ... }';
      const data: JsonValue = JSON.parse(json);
      if (is_json_dict(data)) {
         this.dowork(data);
   }
}

( new Foo() ).main();
```